# ireport : addition of variables into another variable

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have many variables who came from sub-reports, defined like this :

```
variable class : integer
calculation : system
reset type : none
increment type : none
```

I want to make a sum for some of these variables, by example : `$V{nb1}.plus($V{nb2}).plus($V{nb8})`
It works great if I do this into a textfield, but not if I want to put it in a variable (lets call it sum1).

```
property of the variable :
variable class : integer
calculation : system
reset type : report
increment type : none
```

Like this, I obtain the initial value expression.
If I set reset type as none, I obtain *null*.

The textfield containing my variable sum1 is at "evaluation time : report"

So, my variable sum1 is calculated before `nb1`,`nb2` and `nb8` are. I don't know what to do next...

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The calculation type `system` should only be used when you intend to set the variable value directly via a scriptlet. The report engine will not evaluate the variable expression when this is the case, which is why you obtain *null*.

You should change your calculation type to `nothing`, which will set the value by simply evaluating the variable expression and nothing more.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but it doesn't work... I still have my initial value expression (which I set to zero)

Comment: @user1873571 Try also changing your reset type from `report` to `none`.

Comment: @user1873571 What are the values of nb1, nb2 and nb8?

Comment: They're integer, in my example it was 21, 87 and 3. They are initialized once the subreport is executed. At first, they contains nothing

Comment: I have hit the same issue, have you yet to find a solution?